# Secure way to convert a byte array to SecureString with Base64 encoding

Tags: c#, securestring

I have a `byte[]` which I need to encode in Base64 and return as `SecureString`. My current code is as follows:

```
        string privateString = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
        SecureString result = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in privateString)
        {
            result.AppendChar(c);
        }
        // wipe the byte array...
```

The problem is that calling `Convert.ToBase64String` is not secure as it creates a managed string which I can't destroy.
Is there a secure way of doing this?

Comment: Microsoft does not recommend using SecureString https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md it's mentioned in their docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: No. The fact that you have a managed `byteArray` in memory somewhere containing the unencrypted contents, subject to being moved around in memory by GC and/or leaked through snapshots, already means there is little to no point involving `SecureString`. It is extremely difficult to make any effective use of and you typically shouldn't bother, as the offered security is illusory.

Comment: @JeroenMostert having a `byte[]` can be more useful than having a `string`, though; at least you can overwrite it when you're done (without needing to resort to `unsafe` hacks). But yeah; totally agree on `SecureString` etc

Comment: @MarcGravell: true, but then the question just becomes "where did you get that `byte[]`"? Unless it was created ex nihilo or from a crypto RNG call that made sure to track all of its buffers it's very likely to involve another path somewhere where memory was copied. Narrow is the gate to `SecureString` and wide is the path to insecure copies of data... (And that's before we consider the path *out* of `SecureString` of course, which is the main reason this thing doesn't really work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of ways to encode base-64 data without an intermediate string: [`System.Buffers.Text.Base64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.text.base64?view=netcore-3.1). However! `SecureString` is not secure and should basically not be used now. Ever. It doesn't achieve any useful protection against any meaningful attack.